# Which process has PID 0?

Tags: process

I'm looking for the process started in Linux which has  process ID 0. I know `init` has PID 1 , which is the first process in Linux, is there any process with PID  0?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13290/init-process-ancestor-of-all-processes

Comment: Process ID O is SWAPPER.
Process ID 1 is init.

Comment: For `kill`: ["If pid equals 0, then sig is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process."](https://superuser.com/a/1261201/87805)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From the wikipedia page titled: [Process identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier):

> There are two tasks with specially distinguished process IDs: *swapper*
>   or *sched* has process ID 0 and is responsible for [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), and is
>   actually part of the kernel rather than a normal [user-mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode) process.
>   Process ID 1 is usually the [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) process primarily responsible for
>   starting and shutting down the system. Originally, process ID 1 was
>   not specifically reserved for init by any technical measures: it
>   simply had this ID as a natural consequence of being the first process
>   invoked by the kernel. More recent Unix systems typically have
>   additional kernel components visible as 'processes', in which case PID
>   1 is actively reserved for the init process to maintain consistency
>   with older systems.

You can see the evidence of this if you look at the parent PIDs (PPID) of `init` and `kthreadd`:

```
$ ps -eaf
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Jun24 ?        00:00:02 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 Jun24 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
```

`kthreadd` is the kernel thread daemon. All kthreads are forked from this thread. You can see evidence of this if you look at other processes using `ps` and seeing who their PPID is:

```
$ ps -eaf
root         3     2  0 Jun24 ?        00:00:57 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4     2  0 Jun24 ?        00:01:19 [migration/0]
root         5     2  0 Jun24 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
root        15     2  0 Jun24 ?        00:01:28 [events/0]
root        19     2  0 Jun24 ?        00:00:00 [cpuset]
root        20     2  0 Jun24 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]
```

Notice they're all `2`.

Comment: So if PID 0 is swapper, then what is `kswapd[0-9]*`, which on my system has PID 52 currently? It seems to also be responsible for paging.

Comment: @Ruslan - if you have follow on questions please ask them on the main site, comments are not meant for this. Reference this question in your new question.

Comment: well, but when we create a new process using __fork__ child process get __pid 0__?

Comment: @roottraveller not necessarily, whatever the parents PID is where the fork occurred will be what shows up.

Comment: @slm that's not what @/roottraveller is asking.

Comment: @roottraveller no, when you create a new process using `fork`, the child gets a `0` return value from `fork`, because fork has nothing useful to return to the child but needs to return something distinct from an actual PID. But the child itself does not have PID 0, and that zero isn't really a PID - or at least it's certainly not the PID of any actual process.

Answer (score 13):

From [Process Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) wiki:

> There are two tasks with specially distinguished process IDs: swapper
>   or sched has process ID 0 and is responsible for paging, and is
>   actually part of the kernel rather than a normal user-mode process.

Answer (score 13):

The process with `pid 0` is the scheduler,

> Process ID Description:
>   0   The Scheduler
>   1   The init process
>   2   kflushd
>   3   kupdate
>   4   kpiod
>   5   kswapd
>   6   mdrecoveryd