# Process IDs range

Tags: process, posix

On GNU/Linux system I have only seen positive PIDs, but when kernel panic occurred I seen info about process with PID=0. What's it?

On Minix 3 I have seen processes with negative PIDs. Minix is POSIX-compatible system, but [POSIX allows only positive PIDs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_296). What is it?

What variable type should I use in C for saving process ID?

Answer (score 6):

1) This is pager or swapper: [Which process has PID 0?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83322/which-process-has-pid-0)

2) Never used Minix but manual says negative pid in Minix means kernel process. As this is actually part of the kernel implementation, I can't say if that comply or not to POSIX =)

3) You should use `pid_t`

If your aim is maximum portability you should read POSIX and it says:

First, getpid() function returns `pid_t`. `pid_t` is defined in types.h.

Second:

```
   ... blksize_t, pid_t, and ssize_t shall be signed integer types. ...

   The implementation shall support one or more  programming  environments
   in  which the widths of ..., pid_t, ... are no greater than the width
   of type long. The names of these  programming  environments  can  be 
   obtained using the confstr() function or the getconf utility.
```

So you can save `pid_t` value in `long`.
Also notice that by POSIX, `pid_t` is an integer.