# Linux - Use pgrep Command

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, process

I need to know if a process has any children process, so I use the command

```
pgrep -P <ProcessID>
```

Then I get all the children processes. But when I use the command with an empty value and double quotation marks like that:

```
pgrep -P ""
```

As a response I get the numbers: `1,2` What is the meaning of that result?

Comment: Crossposting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49093374/3776858

Answer (score 1):

Running `pgrep -P ""` is equivalent of running `pgrep -P 0`

Process ID `0` has two children with PID of `1` and `2`:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Jun24 ?        00:00:02 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 Jun24 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
```

More info in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83325/215641)

Comment: @octo-developer - did I answer your question?